# Mudar display CSS com variável PHP

Tags: php

Estou querendo que quando $total chegar e passar do 40  a **div="te"** e a **li class="ta"** fiquem com display:block.

CSS:

```
.foo {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    display:block;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
 }
```

HTML

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Meu Contator</title>
    <link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>

    <?php
        $servidor = 'localhost';
        $banco      = 'test';
        $usuario  = 'root';
        $senha    = '';
        $link     = @mysql_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha);
        $db          = mysql_select_db($banco,$link);
        $idUltimoItem = 0;
        if(!$link)
        {
            echo "erro ao conectar ao banco de dados!";exit();
        }

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$total = mysql_num_rows($query);
while($sql = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
}
echo "$total";
?> <br />

   <div id="te" class="<?php echo $total >=40 ? 'foo' : 'hide'; ?>"></div>

 <ul>
   <li class="<?php echo $total >=3 ? 'foo' : 'hide'; ?>;"> <a href="#"><p>INGRESSO</p></a> </li>
 </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não seria melhor deixar tudo no .css ? E usar somente o atributo `class=`?

Comment: sim sim vai na no css os estilos e talz... mas quero saber como faço a função

Comment: É que achei estranho o uso de `style="..."` Pensei que era isso que você queria vou tentar elaborar uma resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não entendi bem o seu loop vazio e também o seu `<li>` está solto, ele deve ir dentro de UL, mas se entendi o problema é apenas na parte do HTML, então vou falar apenas dele, faça assim:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$total = mysql_num_rows($query);
while($sql = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
}
echo "$total";
?> <br />

   <div id="te" style="width: 50px;height: 50px;background-color: red;float: left; display: <?php echo $total >=40 ? 'block' : 'none'; ?>;"></div>

 <ul>
     <li style="display: <?php echo $total >=40 ? 'block' : 'none'; ?>;"> <a href="#"><p>INGRESSO</p></a> </li>
 </ul>
```

Ou então pode colocar tudo no css assim:

estilo.css:

```
.foo {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    display:block;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
 }
```

E o php:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$total = mysql_num_rows($query);
while($sql = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
}
echo "$total";
?> <br />

   <div id="te" class="<?php echo $total >=40 ? 'foo' : 'hide'; ?>"></div>

 <ul>
     <li class="<?php echo $total >=40 ? 'foo' : 'hide'; ?>"> <a href="#"><p>INGRESSO</p></a> </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: amigo a DIV TE funcionou mas na ul li ela fica visivel mesmo se tiver menos de 40

Comment: sim sim... 
 <ul>
     <li style="display: <?php echo $total >=3 ? 'foo' : 'hide'; ?>;"> <a href="#"><p>INGRESSO</p></a> </li>
 </ul>

Comment: obrigado amigo :)

Comment: estranho aqui ainda continua aparecendo :(... vou editar la em cima na pergunta como está meu codigo

Comment: @kaiquemix esqueci do `;` agora acho que esta ok: `<li class="<?php echo $total >=40 ? 'foo' : 'hide'; ?>"> <a href="#"><p>INGRESSO</p></a> </li>`

Comment: hurru agora foi hihi... obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Segue possível solução:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Meu Contator</title>
    <link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>

    <?php
        $servidor = 'localhost';
        $banco      = 'test';
        $usuario  = 'root';
        $senha    = '';
        $link     = @mysql_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha);
        $db          = mysql_select_db($banco,$link);
        $idUltimoItem = 0;
        if(!$link)
        {
            echo "erro ao conectar ao banco de dados!";exit();
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        $total = mysql_num_rows($query);
        while($sql = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        }
        echo "$total";

        $limiteExcedido = $total >= 40;
        $display = "display:none";

        if($limiteExcedido){
            $display = "display:block";
        }

    ?> 
<br />
       <div id="te" style="width: 50px;height: 50px;background-color: red;float: left; <?php echo "$display"; ?>"></div>
        <li class="ta" style="<?php echo "$display"; ?>"> <a href="#"><p>INGRESSO</p></a> </li>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: deu o seguinte erro "( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR) in C:\wamp\www\test_contar_registros\index.php on line 32" que é essa parte:    var $limiteExcedido = $total >= 40;

Comment: Tira o var, confudi as linguagens

Comment: funcionou amigo obrigado :)